# To save an array in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have been trying to save **arrray** data in Mongoose. This is my mongoose schema

```
    var uploadSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    Fbid: String,
    email: String,
    events: [String],
    uplodedImg: [String],

})
```

And this is how i am trying to save,but nothing is being populated in robomongo
What i am doing wrong here

```
 var uploadImf = new usersuploadImformation({
    Fbid : fb_id,
    email: email,
    events: place ,
    uploadedImg : randome  

});
usersuploadImformation.findOne({
    Fbid : uploadImf.Fbid
},function(err,check){
    if(!check){
        uploadImf.save(function(err, uploadImf){
            if(err){
               console.log("Error found");
            }
            else{
                console.log("Saved");
            }
        })
    }})
```

I want to update these fields

```
    {
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a895f520ea9692308ffcf13"),
    "events" : [],
    "uplodedImg" : [],
    "Fbid" : "1661115317267347",
    "email" : "1407258@kiit.ac.in",
    "__v" : 0
}
```

Tried this other code to update and save:

```
    usersuploadImformation.findOne({Fbid : fb_id},function(err, check){
    if(!check){
        new usersuploadImformation({
            Fbid : fb_id,
            email: email,
            events: place ,
            uploadedImg : randome  
        }).save(function(err, uploadImf){
            if(err){
               console.log("Error found");
            }
            else{
                console.log("Saved");
            }
        });
    }
    else{
        check.events.push({place})
        check.uploadedImg.push({randome})
        check.save();
    }
})
```

It should save atleast once, i have not written the case of updating here.

Comment: I'm not getting what exactly you are trying to do. Can you add some more content what you wanted to do?

Comment: I am just trying to save some data and update it in mongodb array, when required.

Comment: But when i tried to save it always result in empty event, and uplodedImg and my others fields are saved as expected

Comment: still not getting what you are trying to do. Can you add one example object with values.

Comment: Edited it, i have uploaded an example obj, and i want to update events and uplodedImg as user require. but all i am getting is an empty array

Comment: You mean it should only save document if it not exist and if it exist in db then just update the required field values. Am I right?

Comment: yes....i even tried other code, let me update it, still getting empty

Comment: let me know if it solved your issue or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change your code something like this,

```
var query = { 'Fbid': fb_id },
    update = {
        $set: { email: email },
        $push: {
            events: place,
            uploadedImg: randome
        }
    },
    options = { upsert: true };

usersuploadImformation.findOneAndUpdate(query, update, options, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
        // **   
    }
    // ** your extra code       
});
```

Here what upsert do is, if the document is not present inside your DB then it will automatically save the document for you.

`$set` will update the given field and `$push` will push place to events array and randome to uploadImg array.

Comment: I am trying now, sorry was out due to some reason

Comment: Yes its working fine, however my event is null, i will see that tommorow, my eyes are burning now. Thanks for your help brother. On a side note why my code isnt working

Comment: Event is working too...thanks for your help. Just help me clarify why my code wasent working